# Angular use Json data in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am closing this issue because the issue has been resolved, 1 problem was I was using `$scope.data = data` (instead of `$scope.data = data.data`). The other reason is because of the answer I selected.

What I am trying to do, is get data (an object) from a json file and assign it to another variable (or $scope property I suppose?).

But when I do this, the object I've initialized gets assigned to my alternate variable before the $http.get() call happens?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Playing with Angular</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="">
    <p>{{ element1 }}</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.data = {};
            $http.get("data.json").then(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
            });
            $scope.element1 = $scope.data.element1;
        });
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.json is very simple:

```
{
    "element1": {
        "sub1":1,
        "sub2":2
    }
}
```

Am I trying to do something that isn't possible in Angular?
And if this question has been answered elsewhere please point me to it.

**Edit**

*One step closer*

I changed the above `$scope.data = data;` to `$scope.data = data.data;`. Which was what my biggest problem was (in my opinion anyways, supported by the fact that no one else saw this).

Now my problem is that I am looking for a better solution than Narain Mittal suggested below. I can place `$scope.element1 = $scope.data.element1;` inside of `$http.get("data.json").then(function(data) {});`, and it will work. This in not what I want.

But Im going to consolidate what exactly I want, then go over to Code Review. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the statement `$scope.element1 = $scope.data.element1;` inside `.then`function  callback, something like this:

```
 $http.get("data.json").then(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data;
       $scope.element1 = $scope.data.element1;
  });
```

The reason it doesn't work for you is javascript execution doesn't wait for the `$http` call to complete before proceeding with the assignment unless you put it in the callback.

Comment: This does not work for me. Neither does it when I call data.element1 instead.

Comment: NMittal is right. You are trying to assign the `element1` property of the `$scope` object before the `get` request comes back. If "this does not work", you need to try harder. You most likely have more than one problem.

Comment: Sebas I am aware my main problem is that I am trying to assign something before the get request comes back (I've tried factories and services to fix this issue, but I can't find something that works).
And please don't underestimate the amount of time I have spent trying to work out this problem. This is the first post I have done to stack overflow because I cannot figure this out.

Comment: @RyanBuchmeier I don't see any other reason why it may not work. Is that possible for you to create a plunk to demonstrate?

Comment: @Narain Mittal, you were right, I do have to put it inside the function callback. However this is not what I would like to use as a solution. There is significant data that will get changed during production. Can you think of another way?
By the way, the reason this did not work for me before is because it needs to be: `$scope.data = data.data`

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that data is a string that needs to be parsed as json.

```
$scope.data = {}
$http.get("data.json").then(function(data) {
     $scope.data = angular.fromJson(data); 
});
```

I have edited this, since i think a better option would be to do the above and to have your template drill into data

```
<p>{{ data.element1 }}</p>
```

EDIT
Sorry, it's [fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)

Comment: So actually when I did it before this, data became an object after the .then call. Now it becomes a string and not an object.

Comment: It will be a string, and JSON.parse or angular.toObject should do the trick

Comment: It's actually fromJson

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse JSON data like this

```
$http.get("data.json").then(function(data) {
       var data = JSON.parse(data)
       $scope.element1 = data.element1
  });
```

Comment: This gives me a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o  at Object.parse (native)" error.

Comment: your json file needs to be in JSON format {
    "element1": {
        "sub1":1,
        "sub2":2
    }
}